# Find and update object into array into array at mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Lets say I have this json at Mongodb:

```
 {
"_id": {
    "$oid": "5b37f4b5fe0cd65b1739641b"
},
"email": "sample@me.com",
"username": "Sample",
"password": "$2b$10$Zpynx8wTgqQftUO3m1tLUO8lNHtBtxl0i7yk84rRkVzcTmB9zO7Mu",
"__v": 0,
"tds": [
    {
        "_id": {
            "$oid": "5b3bebb247737b77b2ecc398"
        },
        "category": "Projects",
        "todos": {
            "_id": {
                "$oid": "5b3bebb247737b77b2ecc397"
            },
            "todo": "something to do"
        }
    },
    {
        "_id": {
            "$oid": "5b3bec41dc270277bae759d6"
        },
        "category": "Main",
        "todos": {
            "_id": {
                "$oid": "5b3bec41dc270277bae759d5"
            },
            "todo": "Other to do"
        }
    }
]
```

}

How can I be able to update a todo? 
e.g.:

```
  {
        "_id": {
            "$oid": "5b3bebb247737b77b2ecc397"
        },
        "todo": "something to do"
    }
```

into

```
  {
        "_id": {
            "$oid": "5b3bebb247737b77b2ecc397"
        },
        "todo": "Lets do something"
    }
```

I was trying at nodeJS, to use select, $push, $set, but anyone was capable to do this. Maybe there is an away to filter that I'm don't know. As I'm stack into this for 2 days I decided to gave up.

Schema:

```
var UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  email: {
    type: String,
    unique: true,
    required: true,
    trim: true
  },
  username: {
    type: String,
    unique: true,
    required: true,
    trim: true
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  passwordConf: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  tds:{}
})
```

;

EDIT:

New valid json with valid ids.

Comment: Where's your code?

Comment: For now, there is no code, every code that I've tried didn't work. But I've used codes such as 'User.update{_id: 'ID HERE', tds: {$elemMatch: {'_id': 'ID HERE'}}}' and User.update({'tds.id': 'ID HERE'}, {'$set': {
    'todos.$.todo': 'TODO HERE',
}}, function(err) { ...} . I'm trying to find a way to do this kind of Find and Update, but as it is so specific, an object into an array of objects into another array of objects, I'm stuck.

Comment: Why is there a `.` after `"_id": {
                       "$oid": "5b3bebb247737b77b2ecc397"
                      }` in your first code snippet?

Comment: Also your second `todos` array does not contains elements wrapped within `{ }` as is wrapped in the first `todos` array.

Comment: Just a mistake, I made a hypothetic json

Comment: There's one more problem when you created this hypothetical json. The object ids are not valid.

Comment: Where's your schema defined?

Comment: I'm sorry for those mistakes, now everything is fine, the json is valid and the schema is already there.

Answer (score 0):

You can update your json data using updateOne() and updateMany() functions in mongoose as shown below :

```
const Users=mongoose.model('user',UserSchema);
Users.updateOne({'tds.todos._id':'5b3bebb247737b77b2ecc397','tds.todos.todo':'something 
to do'},{'tds.todos.todo':'Lets do something'}).then((users)=>{
console.log(users);
});
```